# Write css into javascript code doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css

I have this javascript code for print a div content.

```
function PrintElem()
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=600,width=800');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');

    mywindow.document.write('<style type="text/css">' + @media print {
    .no_print{ display:none;}
    .fav_thumb{width:50%; height:50%; float:left}
} + '</style>');

    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h2>' + document.title  + '</h2>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById("favorite_items").innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/  

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

How can i write some print css for that new window, that the javascript opens?

Comment: First off, the CSS you're trying to add (starting with `@media`) needs to be encapsulated in quotes.

Comment: Works fine if the CSS is quoted correctly https://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/XVMrOe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1 - [Inline Styles](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles) may be applicable to your goal.

This paragraph HTML example of an element using Inline Styles was shown on the prior link.

```
<p style="color:blue;font-size:46px;">
  I'm a big blue, <strong>strong</strong> paragraph
</p>
```

Option #2 - Internal Style definitions

Option #3 - External Style files

[Styling HTML with CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) link covers all three (3) options.